# WPF Combobox Filter or auto-complete

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

How to possible filter wpf ComboBox on text search

My XAML Code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding customerCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}" SelectedValuePath="CustomerId" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="183,146,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.514,0.39"/>

</Grid>
```

MVVM code

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        customerCollection = new ObservableCollection<CustomerModel>();
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 1, Name = "A" });
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 2, Name = "AA" });
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 3, Name = "AAA" });
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 4, Name = "BAAA" });
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 5, Name = "BB" });
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 6, Name = "CC" });
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 7, Name = "CCCC" });
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 8, Name = "DFF" });
        customerCollection.Add(new CustomerModel() { CustomerId = 9, Name = "ABC" });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerModel> customerCollection { get; set; }
    private CustomerModel _SelectedCustomer = new CustomerModel();
    public CustomerModel SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _SelectedCustomer; }
        set
        { _SelectedCustomer = value; }
    }
}
```

How to show the filtered items as typed in the text box of ComboBox.?

Here I want to display on ComboBox items are customers on text searched.

Comment: The code you have given. Works well. Can you tell what you exactly want to filter? CustomerId  or Name. On what basis do you want to apply filter?

Comment: Want to filter based on Customer Name, Here this combobox edit mode, On that text box we can use customer name that time I want to display filtered customers only on that combobox item and we can select that items using arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such builtin property in combobox control. But, you can achieve this by using this [autocomplete textbox/combobox user control](http://www.sottje.net/post/WPF-autocomplete-textboxcombobox.aspx).

Comment: I am tried this but difficult to get selected items , how to get selected item

Comment: Page is no longer there, getting 404!

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.nuget.org/packages/THEFilteredComboBox/
This is control (currently in beta) developed and used by our company